# Diophantine Equation and Congruence Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs $(x, y)$ of integers such that: $$1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2$$
Using congruence modulo 3 and 4, I concluded that $x$ is a even integer, $y=1$ $(mod\ 12)$ but I couldn't use them to solve the problem.

Comment: This is IMO2012 problem 4 and its official solutions exists in different pages on the web.

Comment: @Ghartal that was a functional equation problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry its 2006! Ye lahze ghati kardam!

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find the solutions?

Comment: See here: http://olympiads.win.tue.nl/imo/imo2006/solutions.pdf